# Remote ssh command with arguments

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I know that I can run command remotely from another machine using ssh -t login@machine "command", however I am struggling to run more complex command like this:

```
 watch  "ps aux  | awk '{print $1}' | grep php-fpm | wc -l"
```

I am trying with different kind of quotes however although watch command seems to be firing, it's showing errors like:

> awk: cmd. line:1: {print awk: cmd. line:1:
>   ^ unexpected newline or end
>   of string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is the `$` is expanded by the shell before it is passed to the `ssh` command. You need to deprive it of its special meaning *locally* by escaping it before passing it to `ssh` as

```
ssh -t login@machine watch "ps aux | awk '{print \$1}' | grep php-fpm | wc -l"
```

The error you are seeing is because when shell tries to expand `$1` it does not find a value for it and leaves an empty string which results in incorrect number of arguments passed to `awk`.

Also you could replace your shell pipeline containing `awk` and `grep` with just a simple logic

```
ssh -t login@machine watch "ps aux | awk '\$1 == \"php-fpm\"{count++}END{print count}'
```